# NLTK WordNet verb hierarchy

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet, linguistics

I spotted some problems with WordNet's hierarchy for verbs.
For example,
`a.lowest_common_hypernyms(wn.synset('love.v.02'))` returns `[]`.

Isn't there a common ancestor like `entity` for verbs as well ?

Are verbs even connected to nouns in the same hierarchy ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the top hypernym of any synset, use the `Synset.root_hypernyms()` function, e.g.:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> wn.synsets('car')[0].root_hypernyms()
[Synset('entity.n.01')]
>>> wn.synsets('love')[0].root_hypernyms()
[Synset('entity.n.01')]
>>> wn.synsets('love', 'v')[0].root_hypernyms()
[Synset('love.v.01')]
```

It seems that there's no overarching/umbrella hypernym that covers all `verbs`, unlike `nouns` that covered by `entity.n.01`:

```
>>> root_hypernyms_of_nouns = Counter(chain(*[ss.root_hypernyms() for ss in wn.all_synsets(pos='n')]))
>>> len(root_hypernyms_of_nouns)
1
>>> root_hypernyms_of_nouns.items()
[(Synset('entity.n.01'), 82115)]
```

But you can try to iterate through all verbs, e.g.:

```
wn.all_synsets(pos='v')
```

And try to find the top most hypernyms for verbs (it will be a rather large list):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> root_hypernyms_of_verbs = Counter(chain(*[ss.root_hypernyms() for ss in wn.all_synsets(pos='v')]))
>>> root_hypernyms_of_verbs.most_common(10)
[(Synset('change.v.01'), 1704), (Synset('change.v.02'), 1295), (Synset('act.v.01'), 1083), (Synset('move.v.02'), 1027), (Synset('make.v.03'), 659), (Synset('travel.v.01'), 526), (Synset('think.v.03'), 451), (Synset('transfer.v.05'), 420), (Synset('move.v.03'), 329), (Synset('connect.v.01'), 262)]
>>> root_hypernyms_of_verbs.keys() # This will return all root_hypernyms.
```

Visuwords has a very pretty interactive graph that you can use to look through the WordNet hierarchy manually, http://visuwords.com/entity

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! 
It looked really weird to me as there isn't anything about the subject in the internet except in some academic papers about WordNet

Comment: If we look at Aristotle meta-physical definitions: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-metaphysics/ , it might explain why verb doesn't have an umbrella "sense"

Comment: Possibly, the difference is how wordnet view "things" (i.e. arguments) vs "events/actions" (i.e. predicates) vs "descriptors" (i.e. adjuncts/modifiers) as different. With arguments being subsume-able hierarchically while predicates and adjuncts being hierarchical but not subsume-able. It does somewhat follow's Aristotle meta-physics

Comment: Yeah, verbs don't behave as nicely as nouns.
You can look at [this paper](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/C08-1092) for a fix suggestion for this hierarchy

Comment: Cool, didn't know that someone tried to find a TOP for verbs before. Computationally it's sound but it's hard to really find a top level of verbs cross-linguistically, so the TOP for predicates might not be universally true =(